# Error installing Ruby gem cucumber

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I am trying to do - gem install cucumber but everytime I do it I am receiving -

```
gem install cucumber
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPRetriableError)
        302 "Found"
```

I tried using proxy settings per similar questions on stackoverflow but then the error type varied but no success in it. Here is some information -

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x64-mingw32]

gem -v
2.6.3

gem install http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port> cucumber
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPRetriableError)
    302 "Found"

gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPRetriableError)
    302 "Found"
```

Checked various links which ultimately point to this url - http://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/why-do-i-get-http-response-302-or-301-when-installing-a-gem
But that didn't help either.

Please help.

Comment: Does **gem list** work? Can you uninstall RubyGems?

Comment: Issue **gem env**.  Are there space characters in INSTALLATION DIRECTORY or GEM PATH? Any accented characters? If yes, reinstall in a directory without them.